# How do you get around security warnings when redirecting AppData?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, folder-redirection

I've recently set up folder redirection for my user profile in a domain.

For now, I've redirected AppData, Desktop, Pictures, Documents and Favorites. So far, so good. But now I've noticed a quite disturbing side effect of the whole thing.

Whenever I click any of my pinned elements on the task bar, I get the following warning:

[image]

The shortcuts get synced as well and are no longer trusted. They're located at

```
\\DFS\UserData\Profiles\OliverSalzburg\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar
```

That seems like it could be a problem when rolling it out to the whole company.

Comment: Try adding the DFS namespace and the individual servers that host the DFS shares to the Intranet zone in IE. To solve this organization-wide, that can be set via group policy.

Comment: @RyanRies: I've set that up through GP, but the result is still the same and I'm uncertain how to verify if the zones are actually updated. The dialogs in IE are greyed out and list no URLs at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Ryan's comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/456674/how-do-you-get-around-security-warnings-when-redirecting-appdata#comment500383_456674) I was able to resolve this issue by adding the DFS namespace to the IE Intranet zone. I also added the name of the actual storage server behind it, but I have not confirmed if that is actually required.

Initially I set up a GPO to add the namespace to the intranet zone on a **computer** level through the **Site to Zone Assignment List** found at:

> Computer Configuration → Administrative Templates → Windows Components → Internet Explorer → Internet Control Panel → Security Page.

Additionally, I activated the policy **Security Zones: Use Only Machine** in the hopes that that would be sufficient to resolve the issue. However, that did not have the desired effect.

Only after applying the same **Site to Zone Assignment List** on a **user** level was the issue resolved. This is somewhat confusing, given that the **Security Zones: Use Only Machine** policy is still in effect.

Needless to say, I don't fully understand the solution, but it worked so far.

#### Additional Reading

I found these really helpful while working on the issue:

- [How to configure Internet Explorer security zone sites using group polices](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2012/06/05/how-to-configure-internet-explorer-security-zone-sites-using-group-polices.aspx)
- [Best Practice: How to use Group Policy to configure Internet Explorer security zone sites](http://www.grouppolicy.biz/2010/03/how-to-use-group-policy-to-configure-internet-explorer-security-zone-sites/)